# ¿Como encontrar los números iguales de 2 listas diferentes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

como estan?

Soy nuevo en esta página y nuevo programando. Estoy empezando con Python haciendo unos ejercicios, y hay uno que me quedé estancado, y pasé por acá para ver si alguno me ayuda a solucionarlo.

El ejercicio me pide:

- Solicitar al usuario 5 números y agregarlos a una lista vacía.  (**HECHO**)
- Solicitar al usuario otros 5 números y agregarlos a otra nueva lista vacía.  (**HECHO**)
- Mostrar al usuario una lista que contenga los números que tienen en común las dos listas anteriores  (**AYUDA EN ESTE PUNTO**)

Como ven me falta el tercer punto, que no estoy seguro si hay que usar un for o algun if, agradecería un monton si me ayudan.

Por las dudas les dejo el código de lo que hice en este ejercicio hasta ahora, por si quieren corregirme algo u optimizar el código:

```
lista = []
lista_dos = []

num1 = int(input("Introduce un número: "))
num2 = int(input("Introduce un número: "))
num3 = int(input("Introduce un número: "))
num4 = int(input("Introduce un número: "))
num5 = int(input("Introduce un número: "))

lista.append(num1)
lista.append(num2)
lista.append(num3)
lista.append(num4)
lista.append(num5)
print(lista)

num_uno = int(input("\nIntroduce un número: "))
num_dos = int(input("Introduce un número: "))
num_tres = int(input("Introduce un número: "))
num_cuatro = int(input("Introduce un número: "))
num_cinco = int(input("Introduce un número: "))

lista_dos.append(num_uno)
lista_dos.append(num_dos)
lista_dos.append(num_tres)
lista_dos.append(num_cuatro)
lista_dos.append(num_cinco)
print(lista_dos)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para realizar la tarea de encontrar elementos en común entre dos listas, se puede hacer uso del operador `&` entre dos sets (no voy a entrar en detalles, pero básicamente devuelve un set con los elementos en común).

**Ejemplo de uso:**

```
print(set([1,2,3]) & set([3,4,5]))
```

**Resultado:**

```
{3}
```

Por otro lado, tu código se puede optimizar muchísimo, los inputs y appends se pueden meter en un ciclo `for`, ahorrar lineas de código y dar automatización. Un ejemplo:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    num = int(input("Introduce un número: "))
    lista.append(num)
```

Dicho esto, una buena solución sería el siguiente código:

**Solución:**

```
lista = []
lista_dos = []

print("Primera lista: ")
for i in range(0,5):
    num = int(input("Introduce un número: "))
    lista.append(num)

print("\nSegunda lista: ")
for j in range(0,5):
    _num = int(input("Introduce un número: "))
    lista_dos.append(_num)

print("\nNúmeros en común:")
for i in set(lista) & set(lista_dos):
    print(i,end = " ")
```

Con los `for` obtenemos 5 entradas por teclado (dos veces), y al final imprimimos los elementos en común.. Hay que decir que la salida por pantalla puede ser a tu gusto, yo usé `end = " "` para separar los números en espacios, pero puedes imprimirlos como lo desees.

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos!

Comment: Si funciona!!
Te agradezco muchísimo por tu tiempo y la ayuda! :D